# COLDFUSION: select one checkbox for td(row) in a table loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, coldfusion

In the code below, I iterate through a table.  There are two check-boxes for the desired row.  Once the first box is checked, I want to prevent the user from checking the other in that row.  If the user checks the second, s/he should be able to check other boxes (options).

```html
<cfquery name="data" datasource="#dbMarks#">
SELECT helix_date, Helix_Title
FROM Helix_Events
</cfquery>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row"> 
  <form action="save.cfm">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
   <h2>Select Helix Programme</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mtr mtop">
   <select name="" id="" class="btn-markham">
    <option value="">Semester 1</option>
    <option value="">Semester 2</option>
   </select>
   <button class="btn-markham" onclick="myFunction()"><span class="fa fa-print"></span>&nbsp;Print</button>
   <input type="submit"  class="btn-markham2" value="Save">
   <br></br>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12">
  <table class="table">
   <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Event</th>  
    <th class="mtc">Participation</th>
    <th class="mtc">Support</th>   
   </tr> 
   <cfoutput query="data" >
   <tr>
    <td>#dateformat(helix_date,"dd-mmm-yy")#</td>
    <td>#helix_title#</td>
    <td class="mtc"><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1"> </td>
    <td class="mtc"><input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="2"></td>
   </tr> 
   </cfoutput>  
  </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 </form>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, S.O. works differently than a discussion forum. Please include what you have actually tried to solve the problem. Otherwise, the question may down voted and/or [closed as off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Corrected grammar and phrasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code line .`jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('[type=checkbox]').not(this).prop('disabled', true);` which make the next checkbox disabled on check of current of checkbox. Same way you can remove the disabled checkbox on uncheck using `jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('[type=checkbox]').not(this).prop('disabled', false);`

Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('change',function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){    
    jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('[type=checkbox]').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
  }else{
    jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('[type=checkbox]').not(this).prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<cfquery name="data" datasource="#dbMarks#">
  SELECT helix_date, Helix_Title
  FROM Helix_Events
</cfquery>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
    <form action="save.cfm">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
        <h2>Select Helix Programme</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mtr mtop">
        <select name="" id="" class="btn-markham">
          <option value="">Semester 1</option>
          <option value="">Semester 2</option>
        </select>
        <button class="btn-markham" onclick="myFunction()"><span class="fa fa-print"></span>&nbsp;Print</button>
        <input type="submit"  class="btn-markham2" value="Save">
        <br></br>
      </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Event</th>  
          <th class="mtc">Participation</th>
          <th class="mtc">Support</th>   
        </tr> 
        <cfoutput query="data" >
          <tr>
            <td>#dateformat(helix_date,"dd-mmm-yy")#</td>
            <td>#helix_title#</td>
            <td class="mtc"><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1"> </td>
            <td class="mtc"><input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="2"></td>
          </tr> 
        </cfoutput>  
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>  
</div>
</div>
```